# Failing to access a Godaddy hosted MySQL server from AWS EC2

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2

I have a MySQL server hosted in my Godaddy server. I want to access that database from my EC2 instance. However, I am unable to do so. I have added the public IP of my EC2 instance to the remote MySQL access hosts.

Things I have tried:

1. By using my Godaddy hosted website name as my server name.
2. Using my Godaddy hosted website IP address as my server name.

Every time I try to connect, It gives me the error:

> Connection failed: Unknown MySQL server host '<hostname>:3306' (11)

Script I used:

```
<?php
$servername = "<hostname>:3306";
$username = "<username>";
$password = "<password>";
$dbname = "<dbname>";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

PS: I can successfully connect my MySQL workbench and a locally hosted server to my Godaddy database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `:3306` from `$servername`

Make sure the arguments are correct. `mysqli()` needs port as separate argument as described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

Comment: Thanks! The port is not required it seems! In my locally hosted httpd server though, it works when I give the port in the manner I described above.

Comment: may have different php versions

Answer (score 0):

According to godaddy you need to enable Allow Direct Database Access  for remotely connections.

[Link here!](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/create-mysql-or-ms-sql-databases-36)